# Passing JavaScript variables to anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, selector

I am using jQuery's Ajax method to asynchronously send a POST request with the user `"name"` and `"comment"`values entered in a form with IDs of `name` and `comment` respectively and the `comment.php` page returns an HTML message (success or error) that gets shown in the `#info` div.

So far, everything works perfectly and the comment gets added to the database and is shown at page refresh in the `#comments` table. Now I just want to add the user's name and comment directly into the comments table but I have a problem, I'm not able to access the `name` and `comment` variables from inside the anonymous function that gets called inside the `.done()` method.

Here's my code:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var comment = $('#comment').val();

var data = "name="+name+"&comment="+comment;

$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "comment.php",
            data: data // Provided form data
        }
    ).done
    (
        function(data) // Returned data from URL endpoint
        {
            // Show returned message
            $('#info').html(data);

            var newRowContent = '<tr> <td>'+name+'</td> <td>'+comment+'</td> </tr>';

            $(newRowContent).appendTo( $('#comments') );
        }
    );
```

Apparently, simply adding `name` and `comment` to the anonymous function's arguments doesn't work, and the variables are declared outside the scope, so I'm not sure why they result in empty strings when printed on the table. I'd appreciate the help and an explanation of what I'm not getting here.

**UPDATE:** Here is an example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/achraf52/z97qt7vv/20/) of what I'm trying to do and it works here.

**UPDATE:** I think I've identified the problem, the ID selectors I'm using to assign a value from the field's value doesn't work for some reason, which leaves the variables as empty strings and that's also what gets stored in the database.

**UPDATE:** I finally discovered the reason, the form I'm using is wrapped in a `div` block with `display; none` so to only show the form once the user clicks a "show comments" button, and that works. The problem is the jQuery  value selector `$('').val();` treats "hidden" inputs differently and I've only been able to find answers dated back to 2009-2011 that work for older versions of jQuery and not this one.

I hope someone could answer me with how I can select by ID the value of an input that's inside a `div` with style of `display: none` when it gets displayed and filled by the user.

Comment: They are in scope, and there is nothing in your code that sets them to `undefined`. Do you have any other code that you've not shown us?

Comment: The entire code above is inside a function, that gets called when the submit button is clicked, though I'm not sure it makes any difference to the scope.

Comment: Can you show the complete code? The code as shown should work with no issues.

Comment: try to rename it to test_name and test_comment.

Comment: Renaming the variables doesn't produce any effect. I have updated a question with a JSFiddle of the whole thing. Why the downvote?

Comment: Post all of your code, including the html markup.

Comment: I can't post the whole code as it's heavily divided in an MVC framework but I can assure you there nothing else interfering with the JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, as stated in my 3rd update, the problem was the inputs were in a `div` with `display: none` that makes it hidden at page load and only shown later when a button click shows it. The problem lies in how it's shown.

My old approach was copying the HTML enclosed in a `div` with `display: none` and id `#commentForm` to an empty div using the `append()` method, which caused the input IDs to be present 2 times in the page and thus the `$()` selector return an empty value.

What I did is change the jQuery to just "unhide" the HTML by removing the `style="display: none"` as such:

```
$('#commentForm').removeAttr('style');
```

That, alone, made the input values to be successfully retrieved with the AJAX code present in my question above. I hope this helps someone who might encounter a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

It think this is maybe caused by an **"out of scope behavior"**. You can try to return the data(name,comment) submitted from your URL endpoint and then get those values. Something like:

```
 function(data) // Returned data from URL endpoint
        {
            // First you need to parse the json data
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            // Show returned message
            $('#info').html(data['info']);

            // Then you get the data returned
            var newRowContent = '<tr> <td>'+ data['name'] +'</td> <td>'+ data['comment'] +'</td> </tr>';

            $(newRowContent).appendTo( $('#comments') );
        }
```

> Off course, this assuming that you're returning json data. Hope it helps! ;)

Comment: This is a viable option, but the approach I'm using works for the "update" section of the table. Please check my new update on the issue.